# Узнать объём данных определённых строк или вес выборки?

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Возможно ли как-то узнать сколько весят определённые строки в таблице в базе данных MySQL, либо узнать вес выборки при обработке на сервере. Сделать это нужно либо с помощью PHP, либо средствами MySQL.

Comment: Вес? Weight?  Что это?

Comment: Если нужен объём данных - достаточно вычислить длину всех переменных как длину строк в однобайтовой кодировке - это и будет объём в байтах. Для PHP это - `strlen()`, для MySQL - `LENGTH` либо `BIT_LENGTH` (в битах).


В остальном же, переменная либо ячейка таблицы будет занимать столько места,  сколько отведено под ее тип.

Comment: Хорошо попробую, спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

Cледует учитывать, что размер занимаемый данными суммируется фактически из двух значений - сам объем данных и мета-информация. Например, для размер поля `TINYBLOB` определяется количеством байт отводимых под данные, плюс 1 байт под их адресацию, в случае `BLOB` добавляется еще 2 байта, в случае `MEDIUMBLOB` - 3, а в случае `LONGBLOB` - 4 байта.

Ряд полей имеют фиксированный размер, ряд - переменный.

Размер текстовой информации сильно зависит от кодировки, так под UTF8 отводится 3 байта на каждый символ, под UTF8MB4 отводится 4 байта на каждый символ. Эта информация хранится в системной базе данных `information_schema`. Например, извлечь количество байт, которые отводятся под символ текущей кодировки можно следующим образом

```
<?php
// Вычисляем размер символа в байтах
function bytesInSymbols($pdo, $charset = 'utf8_general_ci') {
  $query = "SELECT
              MAXLEN AS bytes
            FROM
              information_schema.CHARACTER_SETS
            WHERE
              DEFAULT_COLLATE_NAME = :charset";
  $sym = $pdo->prepare($query);
  $sym->execute(['charset' => $charset]);
  return $sym->fetchColumn();
}
```

Вычислим сначала, сколько отводится байт под мета-информацию строки

```
<?php
// Размер мета-информации для типа $type
function sizeOfColumn($type, $precision) {
  $types =
    ['tynint' => 1, 'smallint' => 2, 'mediumint' => 3, 'int' => 4, 'integer' => 4, 'bigint' => 8,
    'float' => function($precision){ return $precision <= 24 ? 4 : 8; }, 'double' => 8,
    'decimal' => function($precision){ return $precision + 2; },
    'numeric' => function($precision){ return $precision + 2; },
    'date' => 3, 'time' => 3, 'datetime' => 8, 'timestamp' => 4, 'year' => 1,
    'char' => 0, 'binary' => 0,
    'varbinary' => function($precision){ return $precision > 255 ? 2 : 1; },
    'varchar' => function($precision){ return $precision > 255 ? 2 : 1; },
    'enum' => function($length){ return $length + 2; } , 'set' => function($length){ return $length + 8; },
    'tinyblob' => 1, 'tinytext' => 1,
    'blob' => 2, 'text' => 2,
    'mediumblob' => 3, 'mediumtext' => 3,
    'longblob' => 4, 'longtext' => 4,
    ];
  return is_numeric($types[$type]) ? $types[$type] : $types[$type]($precision);
}

// Размер мета-информации, занимаемый таблицей
function sizeOfMeta($pdo, $database, $table) {
  $query = "SELECT
              *
            FROM
              information_schema.COLUMNS
            WHERE
              TABLE_SCHEMA = :database AND
              TABLE_NAME = :table";
  $sym = $pdo->prepare($query);
  $sym->execute(['database' => $database, 'table' => $table]);
  $result = 0;
  while($fetch = $sym->fetch()) {
    if(in_array($fetch['DATA_TYPE'], ['enum','set']))
      $precision = $fetch['CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH'];
    else
      $precision = $fetch['NUMERIC_PRECISION'];
    $result += sizeOfColumn(
                 $fetch['DATA_TYPE'],
                 $precision);
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Размер в байтах, занимаемый бинарными и текстовыми данными может быть вычислен следующим образом

```
// Размер, занимаемый строкой
function sizeOfRow($pdo, $database, $table, $id) {
  // Размер занимаемый мета-информацией
  $result = sizeOfMeta($pdo, $database, $table);
  // Извлекаем столбцы, в которых символ занимает 1 байт
  $query = "SELECT
              COLUMN_NAME
            FROM
              information_schema.COLUMNS
            WHERE
              TABLE_SCHEMA = :database AND
              TABLE_NAME = :table AND
              DATA_TYPE IN ('binary', 'varbinary', 'tinyblob', 'blob', 'mediumblob', 'longblob')";
  $sym = $pdo->prepare($query);
  $sym->execute(['database' => $database, 'table' => $table]);
  $arr = [];
  while($field = $sym->fetchColumn()){
    $arr[] = "LENGTH(`$field`) * $bytes";
  }
  if(count($arr)) {
    $query = "SELECT
              ".implode(' + ', $arr)." AS total
              FROM
                $table
              WHERE
                id = :id";
    $sym = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $sym->execute(['id' => $id]);
    $result += $sym->fetchColumn();
  }

  // Извлекаем столбцы, в которых символ занимает несколько байт
  $query = "SELECT
              COLUMN_NAME
            FROM
              information_schema.COLUMNS
            WHERE
              TABLE_SCHEMA = :database AND
              TABLE_NAME = :table AND
              DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'tinytext', 'text', 'mediumtext', 'longtext')";
  $sym = $pdo->prepare($query);
  $sym->execute(['database' => $database, 'table' => $table]);
  $arr = [];
  $bytes = bytesInSymbols($pdo);
  while($field = $sym->fetchColumn()){
    $arr[] = "LENGTH(`$field`) * $bytes";
  }
  if(count($arr)) {
    $query = "SELECT
              ".implode(' + ', $arr)." AS total
              FROM
                $table
              WHERE
                id = :id";
    $sym = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $sym->execute(['id' => $id]);
    $result += $sym->fetchColumn();
  }

  return $result;
}
```

Пусть все функции, перечисленные выше находятся в файле connect.php вместе с кодом, устанавливающим соединение с базой данных

```
<?php
  try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
      'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
      'root',
      '',
      [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true]);
  }
  catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Невозможно установить соединение с базой данных";
  }
```

Таким образом получить размер строки с идентификатором `id = 1` таблицы `tbl` базы данных `test` можно следующим образом:

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php');
echo sizeOfRow($pdo, 'test', 'tbl', 1);
```

Comment: *под UTF8 отводится 3 байта на каждый символ, под UTF8MB4 отводится 4 байта на каждый символ* — в документации несколько иначе изложено: [one to three bytes per character (utf8) и one to four bytes per character (utf8mb4)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode.html)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin А что не так? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-conversion.html На самом деле если провести эксперимент и посчитать размер на практике, то можно убедиться, что с UTF-8 заморачиваться не стали. Под символ всегда отводится максимум.

Comment: да просто с трудом верится, что разработчики так усложнили процедуру сохранения/извлечения данных. ведь весь остальной «программный мир» рассматривает utf8 как набор символов, которые могут занимать от одного до [4 (rfc3629) или 6 (iso10646) байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Они так упростили себе задачу подсчета количества символов в строке, но, да, зарубили идею utf8 на корню, если вы попробуете создать VARCHAR(65536) в кодировке UTF8, у вас это не получится, максимум что получится, это создать VARCHAR в районе 21800. Т.е. каждый символ - 3 байта. А потом когда стали использоваться эмодзи, для которых нужно 4-байтная последовательность разработчика пришлось костылять новую кодировку UTF8MB4. Что тут скажешь: MySQL под управлением Oracle - пропала база.