# MySQL. Как рассчитать объём таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Если я правильно понял, то на объём(размер) таблицы, который она занимает на диске компьютера, влияет тип таблицы, тип полей и т.д.

**Вопрос**
Как рассчитать объём таблицы?
Есть какие-нибудь калькуляторы для этих целей?

Comment: Никак, количество ваших записей в таблице будет отличаться от прогнозируемого с околоединичной вероятностью, а полученный расчет все равно будет бесполезен для экономии дискового пространства, потому что у вас всегда должно быть свободно от 50% места на случай всплеска активности.

Comment: Если размер записи фиксирован, то можно посчитать объём таблицы с достаточно большой точностью. NULL-поля, поля переменной длины, блобы — усложняют расчёт. Если у вас поле `varchar(500)`, где обычно лежат 5 символов, то надо считать именно 5 символов, а не 500.

Comment: @Mark Shevchenko #1. "5 символов..." не важно текст или цифры?  #2.Типы полей на объём таблицы не влияют? #3. К примеру 5 символов это какой объём?  #PS. Я вроде понял.. наверное оформляйте как ответ...

Comment: Возможно вас заинтересует тема http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/269006/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точно объем таблицы можно посчитать только в случае, если размер записи фиксирован. Для этого надо, чтобы:

1. Все поля записи имели фиксированный размер. `char(50)` всегда имеет размер 50 байт, в то время как `varchar(50)` имеет размер от 1 до 51 байт.
2. Запись не содержала NULL-полей.

Размеры типов можно найти в [документации по MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html).

Типы `nchar`, `varchar`, `varbinary`, `tinyblob`, `tinytext`, `blob`, `text`, `mediumblob`, `mediumtext`, `longblob`, `longtext` не имеют фиксированного размера. Если таблица содержит поля этих типов, точный её размер посчитать невозможно. Иногда размер можно посчитать приблизительно с высокой точностью, если понятно, какие данные будут хранится.

Все остальные типы имеют фиксированный размер. `INT` 4 байта, это просто. `CHAR(7)` 7 байт. Размер `NUMERIC(12, 3)` посчитать сложнее, поскольку MySQL упаковывает каждые 9 десятичных цифр в 4 байта.

Каждая запись содержит [служебный заголовок](https://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/10/the-physical-structure-of-records-in-innodb/), который имеет размер от 5 байт. Если NULL-поле имеет значение NULL, оно не хранится в записи, просто выставляется бит в заголовке.

После того, как размер таблицы посчитан в байтах, можно прикинуть, сколько она занимает места на диске. Для скорости MySQL хранит данные большими страницами, блоками размером 4Кбайт или 8Кбайт. Если запись с заголовком занимает 100 байт, а размер страницы 4096 байт, то на странице поместится 40 записей и ещё останется 96 пустых байт на каждой странице. 400 записей займут на диске 10 страниц или 40Кбайт.

Помимо данных, таблица содержит индексы, каждый из которых [тоже занимает место](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-physical-record.html). Если в индексе встречаются поля типов переменного размера, сам индекс также будет переменного размера.

Не смотря на то, что точный размер таблицы определить трудно, на практике достаточно бывает оценить порядок.

**Дополнительно**

Когда MySQL хранит текст, то она и цифры хранит как обычные символы. Скажем, в кодировке UTF-8 все цифры занимают один байт, а русские буквы занимают 2 байта. Чтобы считать корректно, необходимо знать, какая кодировка используется для данного поля.

Типы `INT` и т.д. хранят числа в двоичной системе. `INT` всегда требует 4 байта, где хранится целое число в интервале -2<sup>31</sup>..2<sup>31</sup>−1.

Тип `DECIMAL` хранит числа в десятичной системе, используя [хитрое кодирование](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Densely_packed_decimal), чтобы упаковывать каждые 3 десятичные цифры в 10 бит (каждые 9 цифр в 4 байта).

Типы `BIT(n)` упаковываются вместе в достаточное количество байт. `BIT(3)` всегда будет занимать 1 байт, потому что меньше памяти выделить невозможно. Но два поля по `BIT(3)` также будут занимать 1 байт, поскольку MySQL будет хранить их вместе.

Comment: Вы бы не могли прокомментировать эту тему http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/634210/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9

Comment: `точный её размер посчитать невозможно` - однако можно оценить максимальный.