# Как правильно подобрать типы полей?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Создал таблицу со следующими характеристиками (см. скрин).
Предполагается использовать таблицу InnoDB.
Общее кол-во записей в таблице, думаю 10,0 млн - 30,0 млн..

В обозначении "textxxxxx-000000" условно показаны:
  - "textxxxxx" - текст соответствующей длинны.
  - "000000" - цифры.

Пример:
nomerthe-498798
scrsdgoob-654983

**ПРИНЦИП РАБОТЫ С БАЗОЙ:**
1. **Наполнение** -
   Ввод записей через программу-клиент: единично или пакетно.
   "Пакетно" - имею ввиду, что записи парсятся из источника и попадают в базу с использованием программы парсера.
Или просто импорт.
Импорт(или заполнение) сначала в пустую базу, а потом по мере заполнения таблицы.

**2.** **Операции**.
   **2.1.0** **выборка записей из таблицы**
          **2.1.1** **По внешнему ключу**.
            Количество записей при выборке по внешнему ключу колеблется 1-100 штук. 
   Т.е. максимальное количество записей, которое может соответствовать одному внешнему ключу может достигать 100 шт. записей.
        **2.1.2** **По комбинированным условиям.**
               В условиях может участвовать от 1 до 7 полей
В зависимости от поля, условия выборки могут быть:
 - текст содержит;
 - интервал id;
 - конкретная дата;
 - интервал дат;
В зависимости от ситуации, могут использоваться как одно условие, так и различные комбинации.
   **2.2.0** **Корректировка записей**.
**2.2.1** **Корректировка по одной из клиента**.
Основной принцип работы предполагает корректировку записи по одной, с использованием клиента.
**2.2.2** **Корректировка пакетная**.
Думаю иногда может понадобится функция "найти - заменить"
Пример: "найти - заменить" текст в каком-либо поле по всем записям.

**3. Дубликаты.**
Исключены

**Вопрос.**
Будет ли оптимальными такие типы полей для таблицы с таким составом данных, чтобы обеспечить:
      - 1. минимальный объём занимаемого места на диске?
      - 2. максимальную скорость работы при обращении по внешнему ключу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для `да/нет` лучше завести enum. Как вы планируете хранить дробные числа в поле int? `decimal(7, 3)`

Comment: там где int и значение максимум будет 1000, проще поставить тип SMALLINT и длину задать 4.........там где поле `textxxxxx-00` делать  как TEXT вообще нет смысла......... про поле типа LONGTEXT тем более.....а поле с дробными значениями (предполследнее) не может быть INT

Comment: 1) `textxxxxx-000000` - что на месте иксов и нулей? только цифры? 2) `Цифра с максимальным значением 1000` - бред. Цифр всего 10, и максимальная - девятка. Это если в десятичной СС, само собой... 3) Максимальная скорость зависит не только от структуры, но в не меньшей степени от наполнения и от выполняемых операций.

Comment: @Akina 1) Скорректировал вопрос. Дублирую "В обозначении "textxxxxx-000000" условно показаны:
- "textxxxxx" - текст соответствующей длинны.
- "000000" - цифры.

Пример:
nomerthe-498798
scrsdgoob-654983"

Comment: А теперь расставьте приоритеты. ЛИБО минимум объёма, ЛИБО максимум скорости. Оптимизация одного гарантированно изгадит другое.

Comment: @Akina Если вам не сложно, то не могли бы вы рассмотреть два варианта. Пример: 1)условия один - максимальная скорость, большой объём; 2) условия два - минимальная скорость, маленький объём. Если я вас правильно понял.. Прилагаю таблицу, которая в вопросе на скриншоте, если вдруг вам понадобится.. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sRVZSK5khKEqLXo1HP68Oigxp06rhSHAODd7uUqEEZ0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: **Минимизация объёма** ИМХО. 1) Поля 1,2,4,7,12 - если длина поля фиксированная, заменить VARCHAR/TEXT на CHAR. TEXT заменить в любом случае. 2) Поля 6 и 10 заменить на SMALLINT. 3) Поле 11 заменить на TEXT. 4) Поле 14 - либо масштабировать на 3 порядка и оставить INT, либо использовать DECIMAL. 5) Поле 15 заменить на ENUM('ДА','НЕТ'). **Максимизация скорости** Без подробных данных по наполнению и операциям невозможно дать осмысленных советов.

Comment: @Akina " Без подробных данных по наполнению и операциям невозможно". Дополнил вопрос. Дублирую "ПРИНЦИП РАБОТЫ С БАЗОЙ:
1. Наполнение - ввод записей через программу-клиент. Или просто импорт. Кол-во записей, думаю 10,0 млн - 30,0 млн..
2. Операции.
2.1 выборка записей из таблицы по внешнему ключу. Количество записей 1-100 штук;
2.2 Корректировка записей."

Comment: Интерактивную работу можно опустить, неинтересно. Пакет из 10-30кк записей к импорту в один присест - Вы это серьёзно? Импорт всегда в очищенную таблицу или в имеющую наполнение? Если второе - сколько записей? Возможны ли дубликаты? Выборка - условия отбора только по ключу? или бывают другие комбинации условий? 1-100 - это весь массив, или будет LIMIT? Корректировка записей - пакетная, или по одной интерактивно из клиента?

Comment: @Akina 1. "Пакет из 10-30кк записей к импорту в один присест - Вы это серьёзно?" Я не это имел ввиду.. В сколько желательно в один присест добавлять записей?  По остальным замечаниям скорректировал вопрос.

Comment: _сколько желательно в один присест добавлять записей?_ Смотря как именно добавлять. `LOAD DATA INFILE` - это одно, а `INSERT .. VALUES` - совсем даже другое. В любом случае надо бить данные на небольшие пакеты, обработка которых не тормозит работу других клиентов. Размер пакета определяется экспериментально, обычно получается что-то в районе нескольких тысяч или десятков тысяч записей на порцию. Что же до описанных операций (выборка и корректировки - все) - для них типы полей практически не критичны. Гораздо критичнее наличие индексов, желательно максимально высокоселективных.